# how to acces files in directory in hadoop map job?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

```html
for(FileStatus status : status_list)
{
  FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job5, status.getPath());
}
```

I want to know that I have added directory files in input path. now, how can I use in hadoop map ?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little what is that you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: hello Ashrith, what I want is, I have one directory contains some files. I want that I will pass directory as an Input and I will get list of files in that directory. so, I can access file content and process the data in files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `MultipleInputs` class instead of `FileInputFormat`. Frame work will take care of generating key, value pair for you for each of the file for your mapper.

Comment: almas shaikh, can you provide me one small example of MultipleInputs usage?

Comment: MultipleInputs is for different format data input. but, I have same input format with multiple files.

Comment: Its fine. That's an optional part if you want multiple data format support. But it would od what you need. Have a try.

Comment: solution you provided is not proper. bcz here it's not known how many files are there inside a folder and you can't create that much different Mappers.